# geiger tube dc power supply

Tags: power-supply, step-up, geiger-muller-tube

I have one of these [HV](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/isolated-dc-to-high-voltage-dc-converters/1238293/?relevancy-data=636F3D3126696E3D4931384E53656172636847656E65726963266C753D656E266D6D3D6D61746368616C6C7061727469616C26706D3D5E2E2A2426706F3D31333326736E3D592673723D2673743D43415443485F414C4C5F44454641554C542673633D592677633D4E4F4E45267573743D61303470267374613D6130347026) dc converters and I was wondering if I can use it to supply a small Russian SMB21 Geiger muller tube. What other parts would I need to add not to fry the GM tube? Keep in mind I would also like to add a nice Arduino nano and display and turn it into a simple Geiger counter.

The step up dc dc converter is a EMCO A series A04P

Comment: Interesting tube. Very small. No mica window, so pretty much gamma-only. 500-600 cps max. From the way you write, I think you still have some learning experiences ahead of you regarding Geiger tubes, quenching, and their operation generally. (You'd have written a little differently, otherwise.) One of my first electronics hobby projects (40 years ago) was to design and build a Geiger counter. So it's a good project to learn from. I contacted the physicist who'd actually designed the tube I decided to use and got an education over time from him. He also sold me the tubes I bought! (Cool, eh?)

Comment: Thanks for the input! Nice story! I'm trying to find a new hobby and i always wanted a geiger counter! Cheers mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](https://mightyohm.com/blog/2011/08/geiger-counter-kit-for-chaos-camp-2011-done/) is an excellent reference in everything geiger-countery you might ask. There's a nice [schematic](http://mightyohm.com/files/geiger/geiger_sch_fixedR5R6.png) which shows the complete circuit, including the power supply and the detection parts:
[image: MightyOhm geiger counter]

In general you just need a Mohm-range resistor to limit the current through the tube, and a few transistors/resistors (the "impulse detection" part).

After that it's just simple arduino code (attach interrupt, etc.)

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Thank you so much! Cheers! Keep up the good work!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to stackexchange. Thank you so much for everything!